# How is exp implemented in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

It differs from Python's NumPy's:

```
   exp(-0.305175781250000000) == 0.736993813311010992...
np.exp(-0.305175781250000000) == 0.736993813311010881...
```

yet for most inputs on the case I first checked, they are identical:

```
   exp(-0.476837158203125000) == 0.6207436040675000654687210044357925653457641601562500000
np.exp(-0.476837158203125000) == 0.6207436040675000654687210044357925653457641601562500000
```

Yet, checking on another linear sweep, `-10:.002:10-.002` == `np.arange(-10, 10, .002)` , none of the values exactly match, instead the difference grows exponentially, and signed relative difference, `(a-b)/a`, linearly vs linear sweep of `exp`. `np.exp` [C source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_exponent_log.dispatch.c.src) is fairly complicated and involves beyond-mathematical adjustments (e.g. denormal handling). I'm unsure what to make of the systematic error for a general sweep, and exact equality for a selective sweep, for formula equality.

Is MATLAB's `exp` implementation known?

*(This is not an XY problem. My question is exactly as stated.)*

Comment: This function may help: [`expm1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm1.html)

Comment: The question remains open to an answer specifying more detail on the `exp` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High precision applications that are not ready for floating point errors are generally called "low precision applications".  If your code is sensitive to this, you are screwed.

In fact, if you compute the smallest change that a double precision number can represent at the scale of your number, i.e. `eps(0.736993813311010992)`, the result is `1.11022302462516e-16`, which is exactly  `0.736993813311010992-0.736993813311010881`, so you are 1 bit away between the two answers. Note that the real answer is `0.73699381331101091470592957743439`, so neither of them, its between them.

You can't have a bit-per-bit equal floating point computation in several languages. This is an impossible task to achieve. Any of the following *may* produce a change of 1 bit in a floating point result within the same programming language: library version, compiler version, processor brand, processor firmware, OS, etc

Any numerical software that requires high precision **must** be aware of this systematic errors.

Comment: Even different compiler options will cause changes, and not only to the lowest bit. An optimizing compiler will rearrange mathematical operations, which causes changes to the rounding errors. Never use equality comparisons with floating-point numbers.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question. I figured I should've removed that part. You don't know my use case, which is very edge case and I in no way build products that need such equality.

Comment: Pinning it on compiler etc doesn't add up to me if exact equality holds for most values and only fails for some. It's also possible different formulae agree on said values.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon This does indeed not answer the question of how a proprietary software with a hefty price does things under the hood no.  But I suspect not even everyone at Mathworks has access to that information, so you explicit answer ins unanswerable. But I assume this you knew when you asked the question, therefore I skipped that part.

Comment: The answer is that the exact value is between the 2 that the specific MATLAB/python implementations are giving you, and therefore both are as correct as computers allow. Specifically why one or the other will be down to exact assembly code lines and Arithmetic Logic Unit that the current processor has. The answer to "will the equality hold bit by bit" is always unequivocally "no", and in here I explained why.  Your code must be robust only to a certain `epsilon`, and this value must be bigger than machine epsilon.

Comment: To add to Cris's comment: some compilers will make `a*a*a*a*a*a` -> `(a*a*a)*(a*a*a)` and others may do `(a*a)*(a*a)*(a*a)`. These two operation may produce different bit-by-bit results depending on the value of `a`. This is inherent to doing mathematics with a computer. You won't know how your compiler/interpreter will produce assembly code, you will never know.

Comment: The question is answerable, it's up to whether someone is willing to share. Parts of code become visible with a subscription, I don't know the entire MathWorks model so I had reason to be certain that `exp` is super proprietary. If nobody can answer at this time, that's fine, someone may eventually. Also, you argue `(etc)` vs `(etc)` but don't say that the formulae must be same, yes? Then we're back to square one. NumPy is open source so if there's tests to rule out differences in formulae, that'd also qualify as an answer.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon no, the MATLAB JIT/interpreter is always closed source, its always been. You can see MATLAB implementations of MATLAB functions that use other MATLAB functions, sometimes, but you can't see the interpreters code. Yes, numpy is open source! but it uses C implementations of operations, which are also open source! but produce assembly code that is open source. You really need to get to this level to understand the differences, and again, different compiler options will produce different outputs, as Cris said. You can easily get this difference you show in different numpys.

Comment: As a final note: If you want to ensure 100% the result is the same bit by bit, you need to implement your own version, and call that from each of the languages. That is the only way to have sufficient control over it. Otherwise, you can't test if the implementations may differ for some values.

Comment: As an additional note: if you really need that much precision consider using symbolic computations, at the expense of increased running time